# c++ Base Class Undefined. Including base and subclass in another class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class GameObject which has a vector of Component and Transform.
The Transform is a Component but can be accessed on it's own.
I'm getting a Base class undefined error on Component when I try to include both Component.h and Transform.h in GameObject.

Error Message:

```
    Error   1   error C2504: 'Component' : base class undefined c:\users\pyro\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\engine\main\transform.h 9
```

GameObject.h

```
    #ifndef _GameObject
    #define _GameObject
    #include "Core.h"
    #include "Component.h"
    #include "Transform.h"

    class Transform;
    class Component;

    class GameObject
    {
        protected:
            Transform* transform;
            vector<Component*> components;
    };

    #endif
```

Component.h

```
    #ifndef _Component
    #define _Component

    #include "Core.h"
    #include "GameObject.h"

    class GameObject;

    class Component
    {
    protected:
        GameObject* container;
    };
    #endif
```

Transform.h

```
    #ifndef _Transform
    #define _Transform

    #include "Core.h"
    #include "Component.h"

    //Base class undefined happens here
    class Transform : public Component
    {
    };

    #endif
```

I've found a bunch of other topics, but they don't really address the problem I'm having.
So the question is this: why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Notice that GameObject.h and Component.h are both including one another.  This tends to cause weird behavior where not all definitions are visible at the time that you want them.  You might want to look into that as the actual root cause.

Comment: Is the header guard in `Core.h` correct?

Comment: @JaredC: Judging from the names used in the shown header I'd say it is unlikely that it uses a name which is allowed to be used: They all trample on names reserved to the implementation of the C++ compiler and its standard library...

Comment: To expand on what Dietmar said: don't use names starting with underscore; don't use names with double underscores anywhere in them. (the actual rules are more nuanced than this, but following these two simple ones will never cause you issues)

Comment: To expand on what Dietmar and R. Martinho Fernandes said: This widespread practice of using leading underscore arose because that's what system header files use: "If that's how C++ experts do things, that must be the right thing to do, right?" Wrong. Those system headers use leading underscores because their names won't collide with yours if you follow the rule of not using leading underscores.

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

---

#### 1. Circular dependency

`GameObject.h` includes `Component.h`, and `Component.h` includes `GameObject.h`.

This circular dependency breaks everything. Depending on which file you're "starting from", either `GameObject` will not be visible from `Component` or vice versa, due to the inclusion guards.

Remove the circular dependency: **you don't really need those `#include`s at all, as you're already using forward declarations.** In general, minimise the use of `#include` in headers.

---

#### 2. Syntax error

When you've fixed that, **add in the missing `};` in `Component.h`**.

(Your definition for `Transform` thinks it's a nested class inside `Component` which, at that point, has not been fully defined.)

---

#### 3. Reserved names

This may not cause you a practical problem today, but your macro names should not begin with `_` as these are reserved for implementation (compiler) use.

Comment: 1. This method (as far as I understand) should work, and I've used it in plenty of other places in my code without breaking.
2. Was fixed.
3. That's good to know. I'm going to fix that.

Comment: @Matthew: Nope, it should not. :) The preprocessor is not intelligent, and certainly has no way of knowing what your include guards "mean". `#include` is simple text replacement and if you try to expand your directives by hand you'll quickly see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Matthew: Circular and recursive inclusions are a good idea if you are trying to win an obfuscated programming contest. Otherwise they are going to get you into trouble, just as they have here.

Comment: @Matthew: re "*2. Was fixed.*" Is the missing closing brace in the posted code just a cut and paste error?

Comment: I've never used an OS that can mangle copy/paste operations so badly. Perhaps you should consider upgrading your computer.

Comment: I suppose that begs the question, how do I have 2 classes have references to each other and call functions for each other if I can't do it this way?

Comment: Forward declarations. Example: `class Foo; class Bar { do_something_with_foo (Foo& foo_reference); };`. There's no need to define the class `Foo` here. That forward declaration suffices.

Comment: @Matthew this can be achieved with forward declarations, as you have seen but is a design smell and should usually be avoided.

Comment: @Matthew They can include each other all you need in the cpp files, just not in the headers.  As long as you're using pointers to the types, a forward declaration is enough for the header file.  The header file would only need to include another header file if you were going to actually invoke functions (or take a class by value) in the header itself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I suspect he tried to create an MWE and cut out just a tiny bit too much.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Forward declarations are not a design smell.

Comment: @Lightning No but circular references are!

Comment: @Johnsyweb Well that part is true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Yes. Nearly six years later I can see that I should have been clearer in what I meant :-)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose some source file has a `#include "Component.h"` directive and no other `#include` directives. Here's what happens, in order:

1. The preprocessor symbol `_Component` is defined.
2. The `#include "GameObject.h"` directive in `Component.h` is expanded.
3. The `#include "Component.h"` directive in `GameObject.h` is expanded.
   This does nothing because `_Component` is now defined.
4. The `#include "Transform.h"` directive in `GameObject.h` is expanded.
5. The definition of class `Transform` in `Transform.h` won't compile because the base class `Component` has not been defined yet.

The problem is that you have too many superfluous `#include` statements. For example, there's no need for `GameObject.h` to include `Component.h`. The forward declaration is all that is needed. In general, don't include a file in a header unless you truly do need it. If you do need to do so, you need to be very careful of circular inclusions.